# Smoked component on Lincoln 210 MP control board

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image: smoked component]

Here is a picture of my Lincoln 210 MP welder's control board. I have a broken component, and have no idea how to identify what it is. I cannot find a board schematic, no information at all really. Is there a resource that might have obscure schematics anyone knows about?
The replacement cost for a new board is close to $1,000.00, so I'm very motivated to fix the broken component. Any suggestions?

The control board model for the Lincoln electric 210 MP welder is s31129-2

Comment: Did I miss something? Sorry, I'm  confused. Are you trying to say that part on ebay is what burned up on my board? That would be great if it is, but it looks nothing like the picture I posted.

Comment: https://www.fabian.com.mt/viewer/36791/pdf.pdf Here is a link to the datasheet

Answer (score 1):

[image: PCB]

Here is a picture of the PCB from my welder. As others suspected, the damaged component is a bridge rectifier

Answer (score 0):

That component looks like a full-wave bridge rectifier but there's no way to be certain. Have you actually tried calling Lincoln on the phone for a schemo of this product? They should have one...

Comment: I never even considered that route. For some reason Ive been under the impression a company would rather sell the entire board, instead of give out info for the customer to fix on their own. Great suggestion, thank you!

Comment: I agree it looks like a full bridge rectifier. But beware, the blow rectifier could be a symptom and not the problem. If that's the case it will likely explode again if you replace it and power it back up.

Comment: So whats my next step? How do I troubleshoot the burned component, and what other components are affected as well? This is new for me, and i really want to have the knowledge to fix these expensive control boards. I was searching for the control board schematics and learned Lincoln electric discourages component level repairs, so an electrical schematic might not be easily obtained. Other than give them $1,000.00 for a replacement board, what is my next step?\

Comment: search the web for someone who rebuilds those boards. this "$1000 for a pc board" bullsh*t is common and has given rise to a cottage industry of electronics techs who specialize in repairing specific types of smoked boards. good luck- NN

Comment: This is the reply I got from Lincoln electric after I requested the schematic:                                                                                 
                                                                                                        
 "Thank you for contacting the Lincoln Electric Customer Service Group. My name is Michael and I am part of the Customer Service Team at The Lincoln Electric Company.
This is a manufacturing controlled document, we are not allowed to release this information.
Thank you for choosing Lincoln Electric for your welding needs."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my 210mp. It was the bridge rectifier first in line on the heat sink. Replaced, and everything once again runs great. 5 dollar part and some time probing and troubleshooting beats $1000 board everyday of the week.